# TinyMCE Dom manipulations change modify existing tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE commands and I simply want to convert the `<img src="...">` to an `<a href="...">`

Is there a way to achieve this?

```js
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('.text'))
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.createHTML('a', { href:'test.html' }, 'some line'));
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <img src="text.html" style="display:none;" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the content, select the appropriate `<img>` tags, store the `src`, match the images using a regular expression, construct a new `<a>`, and finally return the new HTML content for each match.

```js
const parse = (html) =>
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);

const imagesToAnchors = (editor) => {
  let content = editor.getContent(), href, rel, target;
  editor.dom.select('img').forEach(img => {
    if (img.style.display === 'none') {
      href = img.getAttribute('src');
      target = img.getAttribute('target') ?? '_blank';
      rel = img.getAttribute('rel') ?? 'noopener';
      content = content.replace(/<img\s*(?:[^>]+)>/, (imgHtml) => {
        const currImg = parse(imgHtml).firstChild;
        if (currImg.getAttribute('src') !== href) return imgHtml;
        return editor.dom.createHTML('a', { href, target, rel }, 'some line');
      });
    }
  });
  editor.setContent(content);
};
```

The following works in [TinyMCE Fiddle](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
const parse = (html) =>
  document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);

const imagesToAnchors = (editor) => {
  let content = editor.getContent(), href, rel, target;
  editor.dom.select('img').forEach(img => {
    if (img.style.display === 'none') {
      href = img.getAttribute('src');
      target = img.getAttribute('target') ?? '_blank';
      rel = img.getAttribute('rel') ?? 'noopener';
      content = content.replace(/<img\s*(?:[^>]+)>/, (imgHtml) => {
        const currImg = parse(imgHtml).firstChild;
        if (currImg.getAttribute('src') !== href) return imgHtml;
        return editor.dom.createHTML('a', { href, target, rel }, 'some line');
      });
    }
  });
  editor.setContent(content);
};

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen", 
        "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
        "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks", 
    ],
    toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    init_instance_callback: (editor) => {
      imagesToAnchors(editor); // Call function
    }
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
  <textarea name="content">
    <img src="text.html" style="display:none;" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img src="#">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

It will change the editor source to:

```html
<p><a href="text.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">some line</a></p>
```

Comment: my instance of tinymce is preconfigured. I cant use "tinymce.init"...but will try your first solution

Comment: @Vzupo can't you just call `imagesToAnchors(tinymce.activeEditor)`?

Comment: tinymce is already integrated and I cant modify those init settings

Comment: @Vzupo in your example, you have access to `tinymce.activeEditor`. Just pass that into the function call.

Comment: i have additional questions

Comment: i am using the version without init....it works but I want it to only work on one set and not every single img on the page...

Comment: my class also has 2 images nested within so I want to limt it to updating only the second img src within that class

Comment: @Vzupo I added some parsing logic to the replacement method call. See the updated code.